# Who fills the field marked 'official use'? Indian or UK official?

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, applications

Hi i want to ask that who is supposed to fill the last part of SU07 form i.e the one for “official use”? Is it to be filled by officials of UK or officials of India?[image]

Comment: I am trying to understand why this is relevant for us?

Comment: Not you, so it is just an academic question. I expect also stamps and ID/codes, but you should never see how it was filled.

Comment: IMO the crux of the question is - Is this form SU07/12 submitted by the sponsor in the UK (where some official will sign it and give it back or forward it) or submitted as part of visa application by applicant in home country (in which case part-2 will be unsigned)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe an Indian official should have much knowledge of UK's Immigration Act 1971 nor of the Immigration and Asylum Act 1999.

Additionally, I don't believe an Indian official would be authorised by UK's Secretary of State to make declarations on UK's Secretary of State behalf.

Based on the above, I would argue this is for UK's representatives.

Comment: Since India got much of its bureaucratic and legislative culture from Britain, have you verified that it doesn't have acts named that, or that it doesn't call its relevant government position "secretary of state"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm that's the seal of the British Home Office on the document, so its a fair assumption that the acts and the persons mentioned in it are pertaining to British jurisdiction...

Comment: I agree that UK's representatives will sign it. But does the visa applicant submit this filled form along with their application and the certificate gets signed by the embassy staff or does the sponsor need to get it signed by someone in the UK and then send it over to the applicant who then includes it with the application?

Comment: Outside of the obvious emblem and the title, it also speaks about Immigration. So it also corroborates the assertion that it is by someone from the country that would grant/deny the visa.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something the UK official (official authorized to grant the visa) would sign.